# Parsing JSON on the Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm using the [ArduinoJson](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson) library. There is a [great example](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/blob/master/examples/JsonParserExample/JsonParserExample.ino) for parsing a single JSON object in the source code. I am attempting to iterate over an array of JSON objects:

```
#include <JsonParser.h>

using namespace ArduinoJson::Parser;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  char json[] = "[{\"sensor\":\"gps\",\"time\":1351824120,\"data\":[48.756080,2.302038]}, \
    {\"sensor\":\"gps\",\"time\":1351824140,\"data\":[50.756080,21.302038]}]";

  JsonParser<32> parser;
  JsonArray root = parser.parse(json);

  if (!root.success()) {
    Serial.println("JsonParser.parse() failed");
    return;
  }

  for (JsonArrayIterator item = root.begin(); item != root.end(); ++item) {
    // unsure of what to do here.

    Serial.println((*item)["data"]);
    // results in: 
    // ParseJsonArray:21: error: call of overloaded 
    //   'println(ArduinoJson::Parser::JsonValue)' is ambiguous

    JsonObject something = JsonObject(*item);
    Serial.println(something["sensor"]);
    // results in :
    // ParseJsonArray:26: error: call of overloaded
    //   'println(ArduinoJson::Parser::JsonValue)' is ambiguous
  }
}

void loop() {}
```

`item` is of type JsonValue. I would like to treat it as a JsonObject and pull some data out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char* sensor = (*item)["sensor"];
Serial.println(sensor);
```